# Java android findViewById in static method of another class

Tags: java, android, listview

I have an activity and one abstract class with static method. In this method I want to render jsonArray in list view.

This is activity

```
public class FeedActivity extends BaseActivity {

    ...

    private void renderFeed(String data){

        try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray d = json.getJSONArray("data");
                RenderLists.renderFeed(d);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

And here is static method.

```
abstract class RenderLists {

    static void renderFeed(JSONArray data) throws JSONException{

        ArrayList feedList1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        ListView feedList = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.feedList); // This isn't working

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, Object> hm;
            hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            hm.put("name", data.getJSONObject(i).getString("name").toString());
            feedList1.add(hm);

            FeedItemAdapter adapter = new FeedItemAdapter(FeedActivity.this, feedList1, R.layout.feed_list,
                    new String[] {"name"}, new int[] { R.id.feedCheckinName});

            feedList.setAdapter(adapter);
            feedList.setChoiceMode(feedList.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        }

    }

}
```

How to get Activity and ListView in static method? Please explain me.

Comment: Yes, I'm just learning! )

Comment: then stackoverflow is a bad place ... try https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: Why would you want to set the views outside of the activity? RenderLists is not needed.

Comment: Coz I want to use this list from different activities. Is it wrong? How to organize it better?

Comment: do not pass ui elements at all ... pass underlying data ... or change method to `setupListViewFromData(ListView feedList, JSONArray data)` ... find listview inside Activity code and pass to the static method

Comment: Thanx! Seems it works! Now just what to do with FeedActivity.this in adapter? Error: not enclosing class..

Comment: feedList.getContext()

Answer (score 0):

Passing them at runtime is probably your only reasonable option:

```
abstract class RenderLists {
    static void renderFeed(JSONArray data, Activity act, ListView lv) throws JSONException{
        ...
    }
}
```

Even so, remember that a `view` cannot be updated except on the UI thread.

If that doesn't work for you, then you will probably have other problems (memory leaks, NPE's, etc) although you could use class level `setters` (but that's a lot like the above).